# Finding a resource for CorelDRAW X6's Object Model

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I have asked this on the Stack Exchange Graphic Design forum but that doesn't see much traffic so although this is not your typical programming question I felt I had a better chance of getting an answer here...

Is there, and if so, could somebody please point me to, an online resource for the CorelDRAW X6 Object Model? Something similar to the Object Browser within CorelDRAW, that contains a complete listing of all objects, object members, methods, properties, member function definitions, classes, etc.. I only have CorelDRAW on my work computer and I would like to be able to peruse the Object Model and see the available methods and functions and what types they take for their parameters while at home.

And while I'm at it, could somebody recommend a good online resource for VBA programming in general.

Comment: Take a look at [API documentation](https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/18). IMO there is no VBA programming in general, only for certain applications, so you have to choose the one. Or you may check some [links](https://www.google.com/search?q=msdn+vb6+reference).

Comment: Thank you. That's what I'm looking for. MUCH appreciated.. Although this is for X7 and above I am hoping that not a lot has changed as far as the API goes..